# Zend + Soap Server + Doctrine, Error with serviceLocator/serviceManager

Tags: php, soap, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I'm trying to expose some data with soap.

here's my controller holding the server (everything is normal here):

namespace Application\Controller;

```
use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;
use Zend\Json\Json;
use Zend\Soap\Server;
use Zend\Soap\AutoDiscover;

class ExportController extends AbstractActionController
{
private $_options  = array('soap_version' => SOAP_1_2);
private $_URI      = '/export';
private $_WSDL_URI = '/export?wsdl';
private $wsdl;

public function indexAction() {

    if (isset($_GET['wsdl'])) {
        $this->handleWSDL();
    } else {
        $this->handleSOAP();
    }

    return $this->getResponse();
}

private function handleWSDL() {
    $serverUrl    = strtolower(dirname($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL']))."://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].":".$_SERVER['SERVER_PORT']."/Moving-BO/public";
    $autodiscover = new AutoDiscover(new \Zend\Soap\Wsdl\ComplexTypeStrategy\ArrayOfTypeSequence());

    $autodiscover->setClass('Application\WebService\ExportClass')
                 ->setUri($serverUrl.$this->_URI)
                 ->setServiceName('MySoapService');
    $autodiscover->handle();
    $this->wsdl = $autodiscover->generate();
}

private function handleSOAP() {
    $serverUrl = strtolower(dirname($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL']))."://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].":".$_SERVER['SERVER_PORT']."/Moving-BO/public";
    $soap      = new Server($serverUrl.$this->_WSDL_URI, $this->_options);

    $soap->setClass('Application\WebService\ExportClass');
    $soap->handle();
    }

}
```

then here is the class I'm exporting:

```
namespace Application\WebService;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorAwareInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManagerAwareInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManagerInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Zend\Json\Json;
use Parcours\Entity\Parcours;

class ExportClass implements ServiceLocatorAwareInterface
{


protected $em;

public function setServiceLocator(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator) 
{ 
    $this->serviceLocator = $serviceLocator; 
    return $this; 
}

public function getServiceLocator()
{ 
    return $this->serviceLocator; 
}

public function setEntityManager(EntityManager $em)
{
    $this->em = $em;
}

public function getEntityManager()
{
    $this->em = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager');
    return $this->em;
}


/**
 * Dit bonjour!
 *
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function helloWorld(){
    return 'coucou';
}

/**
 * Retourne le titre d'un parcours
 * 
 * @param integer $id
 * @return array
 */
public function getParcours($id){

    $parcours = $this->getEntityManager()->getRepository('Parcours\Entity\Parcours')->findOneBy(array('id'=>$id));

    return $parcours->toArray();
}

}
```

I also have a test client, the first function: helloWorld() is working fine but the second one: getParcours($id) is returning the following error:

```
 Call to a member function get() on a non-object
```

It seams like getServiceLocator() is returning null.  I'm using a similar piece of code an AbstractActionController: ParcoursController which is working great. Why can't I do that here?

[EDIT]
Ok I've tried something else, instead of using the EntityManager in the ExportClass I've made a get function in my ParcoursController and call this function into the ExportClass. My ParcoursController is already using the EntityManager to display my data into pages so it should work. But the result is the same.
It seems like i should somehow pass my serviceLocator through the SOAP service. I don't think that's a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

OK great I nailed it.

Here is my working conf, hope it helps someone.

All changes from the above example were:

A: added this to module.php (ExportModel is ExportClass from last example i just changed name and namespace)

```
return array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'Application\Model\ExportModel' => 'Application\Model\ExportModel',
        ),
)
```

B: I gave the instanciated model to my SoapServer

```
private function handleSOAP() {
    $exportModel = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Application\Model\ExportModel');
    $serverUrl = strtolower(dirname($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL']))."://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].":".$_SERVER['SERVER_PORT']."/Moving-BO/public";
    $soap      = new Server($serverUrl.$this->_WSDL_URI, $this->_options);

    $soap->setClass('Application\Model\ExportModel');
    $soap->setObject($exportModel);
    $soap->handle();
```

That's all.